# How do we write $x\sqrt{x^2+1}$ in terms of $\sinh(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to write $x\sqrt{x^2+1}$ as something that will have $\sinh$.

So far: $x\sqrt{x^2+1} = 2\sinh\left(\frac{2}{\sinh(x)}\right)$ Is this correct? If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: @gebruiker: Thanks a lot for the welcome! I am trying to solve a complex integral.

Comment: It is important to understand from this question that sometimes $f^{-1}$ does not mean $\frac 1 f$, but rather the inverse function of $f$.

Comment: @Alex M.: thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression given in the OP is not correct.  Note that we have

$$\sinh (2z)=2\sinh(z)\cosh(z)$$

If we let $z=\text{arsinh}(x)$ where $\text{arsinh}(x)$ is the inverse hyperbolic sine function, then

$$\sinh(2\text{arsinh}(x))=2x\cosh(\text{arsinh}(x))=2x\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$x\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac12 \sinh(2\text{arsinh}(x))$$

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can just plug in some number into your equation and it won't hold, showing that it isn't true. Did you by some chance mean to use the inverse of sinh, Arcsinh: $\sinh^{-1}$, and not $\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}$?

If so, then the formula can be proven using addition rules for hyperbolic functions and identities. Here's the ones you need.

$\sinh(2x) = 2\sinh(x)\cosh(x)$

$\cosh^2(y) - \sinh^2(y) = 1$. What happens when y = $\sinh^{-1}(x)$?